# Symfony2 - Homepage cache after user logout

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, browser-cache, logout

I have a login function on a symfony2 project. All works well, except if you do a logout from the homepage, the Logout Link should change to Login, but it stays the same until a page refresh with CTRL + F5.

If the logout is done from any other page except the homepage, the the link change works well.

Any idea why?

UPDATE: Set cache 0 was set:

```
$url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('homepage');
$response = new RedirectResponse($url);
$response->setPrivate();
$response->setMaxAge(0);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(0);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);
```

Comment: What value is in HTTP header `Cache-Control` of your homepage?

Comment: Arn't there any redirect loops?

Comment: @jkucharovic, Cache-Control: max-age=3600. However, we tried to set no cache trhough symfony response but still the same issue.

Comment: @Saleniex, no redirect loops, normal redirect on homepage after logout.

Comment: what are the HTTP status codes of /logout page and then homepage? you can find out for example in chrome developer toolbar or firebug console. first one (/logout) should be 302, second one (homepage) should be 200 (you need to use 'persist' feature to see both of them). Also, is this behavior in all the browsers ?

Comment: @Miro, /logout page returns 302. However, the homepage do not return anything, in the firefox Net I can only see /logout

Comment: that is weird, you should see 302 /logout, then 200 /, and then all the assets (images,js,css,..) on homepage. try different browser - chrome and his developer toolbar (ctrl+shift+i) - network tab, [x] preserve log

Comment: @Miro, after checking a bit more, it seems the logout returns this: `Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Cannot redirect to an empty URL."`

Comment: @Milos, can you also show WHERE is this exception thrown, or is it secret ?

Comment: @Miro, the exception was inserted b<y using the setMaxAge(0);, now it is ok but still the initial issue of cache

Comment: does it work with simple redirect response (without all cache affecting functions) ? also can you post whole event listener (i guess it is logout event listener) ?

Comment: @Miloš are you using custom logout handlers?

Comment: Hi All, the issue ahs been fixed, this was nginx that had: `include custom_cache_headers;`, removing this, all is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 24h of debuging, the error had nothing to do with Symfony, it was the nginx setting:

```
include custom_cache_headers;
```

once this removed, the homepage was refreshed correctly.